# issue with O365.Calendar.GetTables() method

Tags: outlook, office365, sharepoint-online, powerapps

When using the method `Office365.CalendarGetTables().value` I don't get all the calendars available in my outlook. I have connected my outlook to a couple of SPO calendars but when I try to retrieve them in power-app it shows only my old calendars in the drop-down .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your datasource, it must be Office 365 Outlook.
2. set the Items property to: Office365.CalendarGetTables().value.
3. And then you can insert a Gallery to show the list of calendar items.
4. For this set the Items property to: Office365.CalendarGetItems(calendarDropDown.Selected.Name).value

Comment: Thanks Mayur for your answer , i figured out what the problem is it was an SPList with Calendar View and an SP calendar i was trying to connect to that why it wasn't retrievable by GetTables method()